# Trying to deploy fullstack RoR app to heroku but has blank frontend

Tags: reactjs, node.js, ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack

I have a Ruby on Rails, Node, react redux app I'm trying to deploy to heroku. I've worked my way through the deployment stage, and gotten it successfully hosted however it results in a blank frontend. When I encountered this locally, it was because I forgot to run webpack, but webpack appears to be running fine in heroku.

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"webpack": "webpack --watch",
"start": "rails server",
"postinstall": "webpack -p"
},
```

The logs when I access the existing app with a blank frontend:

```
2024-03-12T03:31:36.570040+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2024-03-12T03:31:36.569942 #25]  INFO -- : [a108b8e4-c844-43c3-bc59-9805eff1a374] Started GET "/" for 174.116.115.144 at 2024-03-12 03:31:36 +0000
2024-03-12T03:31:36.570923+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2024-03-12T03:31:36.570848 #25]  INFO -- : [a108b8e4-c844-43c3-bc59-9805eff1a374] Processing by StaticPagesController#root as HTML 
2024-03-12T03:31:36.571272+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2024-03-12T03:31:36.571237 #25] DEBUG -- : [a108b8e4-c844-43c3-bc59-9805eff1a374]   Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb 
2024-03-12T03:31:36.571315+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2024-03-12T03:31:36.571297 #25] DEBUG -- : [a108b8e4-c844-43c3-bc59-9805eff1a374]   Rendering static_pages/root.html.erb within layouts/application 
2024-03-12T03:31:36.572873+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2024-03-12T03:31:36.572816 #25] DEBUG -- : [a108b8e4-c844-43c3-bc59-9805eff1a374]   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."session_token" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]] 
2024-03-12T03:31:36.572977+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2024-03-12T03:31:36.572955 #25]  INFO -- : [a108b8e4-c844-43c3-bc59-9805eff1a374]   Rendered static_pages/root.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.6ms | Allocations: 384) 
2024-03-12T03:31:36.573402+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2024-03-12T03:31:36.573370 #25]  INFO -- : [a108b8e4-c844-43c3-bc59-9805eff1a374]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 2.1ms | Allocations: 629) 
2024-03-12T03:31:36.573520+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2024-03-12T03:31:36.573500 #25]  INFO -- : [a108b8e4-c844-43c3-bc59-9805eff1a374] Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 827) 
2024-03-12T03:31:36.574661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=app-5dfac8c6817e.herokuapp.com request_id=a108b8e4-c844-43c3-bc59-9805eff1a374 fwd="174.116.115.144" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=1855 protocol=https 
2024-03-12T03:31:36.658456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=app-5dfac8c6817
```

Comment: Open up your browser console and look for any JS errors. Also, I don't think webpack should be running in production at all. It should be emitting a static bundle that gets deployed with your app code.

Comment: Do you have all the required [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)?